# How to create proper locator for bootstrap dropdown list - XPath or any convinient when each locator of this element is messy

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenide

I have some piece of html with boostrap dropdown list:

```
<div class="Box-sc-106yp7x-0 SearchBareeu__CategorySelectorWrapper-sc-2tpr15-8 lnyoNZ"><div class="Box-sc-106yp7x-0 Flex-sc-1w817v2-0 CategorySelector__FlexWrapper-sc-97y5w2-0 kBrXmV"><div class="Box-sc-106yp7x-0 SelectInput__Container-sc-169omlt-1 jVHySC"><div><div class="Box-sc-106yp7x-0 Flex-sc-1w817v2-0 dd-header SelectInput__InputContainer-sc-169omlt-7 kyJRJI" data-testitd="bar-category-selector-weu_SelectInput_InputContainer"><div class="SelectInput__TextContainer-sc-169omlt-3 gKnTHQ"><span color="text" class="Box-sc-106yp7x-0 Text-sc-10gb8b4-0 SelectInput__StyledText-sc-169omlt-0 jDnjaV">Wszystkie kategorie</span><span class="SelectInput__Value-sc-169omlt-4 gmvvmW"></span></div><div class="Box-sc-106yp7x-0 Flex-sc-1w817v2-0 SelectInput__ArrowContainer-sc-169omlt-2 fNZDGv"><svg width="21" height="33" viewBox="0 0 21 33" fill="currentColor" class="SelectInput__ArrowDown-sc-169omlt-5 jMgpdX"><path d="M21 3.85L7.94595 16.5L21 29.15L17.027 33L1.18875e-06 16.5L17.027 -1.74303e-07L21 3.85Z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

And I copied xpath and added in IDE like below. However its not green as string. I know xptah is not created with proper way.

Do you have any suggestions to make xpath green in ide or better locator for this???
I would like to click on it and select option from bootstrap dropdown list.
Thx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the XPath. Most likely, you have the [Selenium UI Testing](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13691-selenium-ui-testing) plugin installed in IntelliJ IDEA. This plugin provides syntax highlighting of the XPath expression. Thus it doesn't look like a plain String.

I see in the above HTML snippet that an inner `div` element has a custom attribute: `[data-testitd="bar-category-selector-weu_SelectInput_InputContainer"]`. So, you can use this selector instead of the complex and really unreadable XPath expression:

```java
SelenideElement innerDiv = $("[data-testitd='bar-category-selector-weu_SelectInput_InputContainer']");
```

If you still need namely the parent div, then a partial class can be used of that element:

```java
SelenideElement parentDiv = $("[class^='SearchBareeu__CategorySelectorWrapper']");
```